# How to convert Elasticsearch Java API Client into OSGI bundle?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, osgi-bundle, bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

I want to convert Elasticsearch Java API Client into an OSGI bundle as it is not readily available anywhere. I tried the following command to create one on my own but it not work. I also tried maven bundle plugins but it resulted in the same error. What am I doing wrong?

```
jar cvfm osgi-elasticsearch-java-8.0.1.jar ./MANIFEST.txt elasticsearch-java-8.0.1.jar
```

The MANIFEST use is as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Bundle-Category: OSGI ELK

Bundle-Description: Elastic Search Client Bundle

Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2

Bundle-Name: OSGI ELK - HG

Bundle-SymbolicName: osgi-elk.hg

Bundle-Version: 1.7.0

Bundle-ClassPath: .,elasticsearch-java-8.0.1.jar

Export-Package: co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch, co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices, co.elastic.clients.json, co.elastic.clients.json.jackson, co.elastic.clients.transport, co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client
```

The following classes are not available after installing the manually created Elasticsearch Java API Client OSGI bundle to a OSGI container.

```
co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch -- Cannot be resolved
co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices -- Cannot be resolved
co.elastic.clients.json -- Cannot be resolved
co.elastic.clients.json.jackson -- Cannot be resolved
co.elastic.clients.transport -- Cannot be resolved
co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client -- Cannot be resolved
```